# C# dataGridView update changes to database with another thread

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, datagridview

I want to update changes to database with another thread, because when i change more than 100 cell value the form is freeze for a few seconds.

I try a lots of solution, but i was always get this error

> There is already an open `DataReader` associated with this `Connection`
>   which must be closed first.

How can i solve this?
Without threading the database updated with this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();

        if (changes != null)
        {
            MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
            mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception _ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have is completely straightforward:

> There is already an open `DataReader` associated with this `Connection` which must be closed first

You have to close existing connection to the database, you should not leave it in the open state. This can be done with closing (or disposing) the connection or adapter, which you clearly do not do.

Also, you should remove the database logic from your UI - it is terrible design. If you want to handle some event in background, you can use the `async/await` with [asynchronous event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) with some `Task` firing in background.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(updateChanges);
thread.Start();

private void updateChanges() 
{
    //here your code to update changes.        
}
```

However, if you are updating any UI component within the updateChanges() function you will have to use an InvokeRequired.